# What is the counter for languages

Tags: counters

I've looked this up in a few different dictionaries and the only word I got was 「か国語」written in a few different ways. but all of them contain 「国語」which I have come to understand means national language. Does this only refer to national languages for example:

> スイスは三か国語があります。ドイツ語とフランス語とイタリア語。

or can this be used in other contexts

I am looking for a way to talk about how many languages one knows, and I don't trust google translate enough to believe what it says about just using 「言語」.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use ２か国語, ３か国語 etc. to talk about how many languages one speaks, as in...

> 「私は、**３か国語**が話せます。」
>   「彼は、フランス語とドイツ語と英語の**３か国語**が話せます。」

You can also use 言語, as in...

> 「僕は、フランス語とドイツ語と英語の**３つの言語**が話せます。」

You could also use terms like バイリンガル, トリリンガル, マルチリンガル, as in:

> 「私は、フランス語と英語の**バイリンガル**です。」
>   「彼女は、フランス語と英語とドイツ語が話せる**トリリンガル**です。」

Comment: As for your example sentence, I think it'd sound more natural if you said it as: 「スイスでは、３か国語が (or ３つの言語が or ３つの公用語が) 使われています。ドイツ語とフランス語とイタリア語です。」 or 「スイスでは、ドイツ語とフランス語とイタリア語の３か国語が (or３つの言語が or ３つの公用語が) 使われています。」

Comment: I guess か国語 won't work for something like Esperanto?

Comment: @kuchitsu I would defer to using Xつの言語 in that case as this is more strictly "language" and not "national/official language (of a nation)"

Comment: How would you then go and say 'second' language. 第２つの言語／第二か国語？ or would you use 目?

Comment: @dunno 第二言語/第二の言語

Answer (score 4):

語 means "a language" and "a word". 三か国語 isn't divided into 三か and 国語 but 三か国 and 語. And 国語 means "nation language" and probably it means official language.

Your example is a bit unclear. We can't judge whether it means they are official languages or not. If you clearly want to tell that they are official languages, you can say "スイスには三つの公用語があります。ドイツ語とフランス語と英語です."

Comment: スイスの公用語の中、英語はまだ属されていないと思います：）

Comment: そうですか。例文についての解説なので。

Answer (score 0):

> スイスは三か国語があります。ドイツ語とフランス語と英語。

(1) 「三か国語」で合っています。
(2) 「スイスは三か国語があります」とは言わず、「スイスでは三か国語が使われています」と言います。
(3) [ここ](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1370593178)の説明によると「三か国語」より「三カ国語」と書いた方が新聞の書き方と同じようです。
(4) 「国語」と「言語」とを使って質問者が提示した例を使って表現すると、「スイスで使われている言語はドイツ語とフランス語と英語の三カ国語です」と言いますが、「スイスで使われている国語はドイツ語とフランス語と英語の三カ国語です」とは言いません。また、「スイスで使われている言語はドイツ語とフランス語と英語の三言語です」とも言いません。不思議ですね。
(5) 実際にスイスで使われている言語は、[ここ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switzerland#Languages)の資料によると「ドイツ語とフランス語と英語」ではないようです。

---

## EDIT

質問者の質問はChocolateさんのコメントで指摘されているとおり、私が勘違いしておりました。そして、Chocolateご自身の回答は、質問者の質問に的確に回答されているように思います。（+1）

「スイスは三か国語があります。ドイツ語とフランス語と英語。」という例文が何だか変だと思いましたので、それの指摘に専念しておりました。専念したついでに、更に伝えたいことがありますので、追加したいと思います。

(6)「あります」について
世界にはたくさんの言語がありますが、仮に全部でドイツ語とフランス語と英語の三カ国語だけだとします。そのとき、「スイスには三カ国語があります」とは言えませんが、「**世界には**三カ国語があります」とは言えます。但し、「スイスは」「世界は」ではなく、「スイス**に**は」あるいは「世界**に**は」というのが正しい表現です。

(7) 「公用語」について
「スイスで使われている**言語**はドイツ語とフランス語と英語の三カ国語です」あるいは「スイスで使われている**言葉**はドイツ語とフランス語と英語の三カ国語です」と言えますが、「公用語」は「使われている」という表現と同時に使うことには適していません。従って「スイスで使われている**公用語**はドイツ語とフランス語と英語の三カ国語です」という表現は正しくありません。正しくは「スイスで定められている（または規定されている）公用語はドイツ語とフランス語と英語の三カ国語です」と言うべきです。「定められている」と「使われている」とを混ぜて表現すると、「スイスで定められている（または規定されている）公用語はドイツ語とフランス語とイタリア語（の三カ国語）ですが、実際に使われているのは、ドイツ語とフランス語と英語（の三カ国語）です」　なお、例に挙げた言語はあくまでも仮定のものです。

Comment: あの、、、質問は、「Does this only refer to national languages for example: スイスは三か国語があります。ドイツ語とフランス語と英語。 or **can this be used in *other contexts* ? I am looking for a way to talk about *how many languages one knows*** 」だと思うんですけど・・・

Comment: @Chocolate: ご指摘ありがとうございます。内容を読むと確かにそのとおりですが、ＯＰの質問は質問のタイトルにある「言語の助数詞は何ですか？」と理解しました。まずは「か国語」で合っていると言いたかったのです。ところが、ＯＰがこれは問題なしとして挙げているだろう例文が何だか変なのでついそっちだけを回答しました。